# Large test dataset in repository

Tags: git, testing, repository

Suppose I'm developing some open-source software, written in an interpreted language, managed as a Git repo, that requires a large dataset (+300 MB) for basic testing.

Should the test data go into the same repository as the source code, with a `compileToZipFile.sh` script for publishing releases?  Would it be better to store as two separate repositories, a *srcRepo* and *testRepo* ?

Any best practices/conventions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose the best answer to this question would be based off of the need.

At my work, we segregate our code/test data *by environment type* like:

- Test
- QA
- Staging
- Production

Certain environments have the same data as production, while others have older (or completely different) data.  The benefits of this are:

- Sandboxes to test, implement and 'play' with new ideas/technologies.
- You aren't affecting the live, customer-facing data.
- Integrated tests can be catered to/focused on certain aspects that are agnostic to the main code base.

Now, as to your questions... as I mentioned above, the segregation of data allows for us to rapidly make changes and implement new features since the data we use is focused on *what we are testing*.  We have three trunks that all have independent test data that is specific to what needs to be tested.  When testing the `View` we have a set of tests, when testing the `Model` we have another set of tests and when testing the `Controller` we have yet another set of tests.  Lastly, we have an over-arching set of integration tests that run when a new build is released.  In all cases but the last one, the tests live with the component they were created for; but again, since they are integration tests, it makes sense that they are kept separately of the three pieces they verify.

I think your idea is a solid one.